# LESS @import & Web Essentials 2012

Tags: less, web-essentials

In my web project I have split my CSS into separate LESS files for maintenance reasons. I have  a file called config.less acting as a master file that imports the other less files, using @import directives.

The problem with this setup seems to be that I get a lot of "Undeclared variable" & "Undeclared mixin" while editing my LESS files, for instance while adding a property variable called @textColor in base.less, that is declared in another less file called variables.less. Is there any way of making web essentials aware of variables and mixins being defined in external less files?

Another thing that seems to be tripping up Web Essentials is when I'm using the nested media query feature of LESS:

```
.some-selector {
    background: #000;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        background: #fff;
    }
}
```

The nested @media declaration gets a red underline, and on hover it says "Unexpected '@' block in the style rule". Hovering the nested background property shows a "Validation: 'color' isn't a valid HTML tag.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give an answer regarding the `@media` issue with Web Essentials, but I can give advice on the variables and mixins issue.

Basically, change your `config.less` file to have the `variables.less` and any other mixin files to be `@import-once`, then also add `@import-once 'variables.less` into each file that uses variables from it (do the same for any mixin files used).

What this does is imports the file if you are working on it (like your `base.less`), but when all the files are compiled by `config.less`, it will only import the `variables.less` once, and not again for each file that also references the `variables.less`.

Comment: For some reason import-once is not working for me.  I have a main style.less file which only contains imports.  

From there I import-once a mixin.less file which declares a .clearfix class and the class is included like it should be...  Good.  

Now in another file I also import-once the mixin.less file to get intellisense, and then import-once that file to the main style.less.  I would think it should only include the .clearfix class once, but unfortunately it is including it twice? any Ideas?

Comment: Thanks @ScottS! This was exactly what I was looking for. Should have bothered reading the LESS documentation more thoroughly :) According to the docs, `@import-once` will be the default behaviour of `@import` starting from v. 1.4.0.

Comment: @MattyP: That style.less sounds like the equivalent of my `config.less` file. In that case we seem to have quite similar setups. So the compiled `style.less file` is containing the `.clearfix` class twice?

Comment: @MattyP: I don't have a clear cut answer. There is still much discussion going on with `@import` and `@import-once` behavior that [may be resolved in 1.4.0](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/issues/19). I can only state that you _should not_ be seeing two `.clearfix` classes showing up based on what you have stated, but if you are, then something else is going on that may be a further bug.

Comment: @Unless Yes, import-once is not solving my problems.... I'm using Visual studio and web essentials (web tools now) for less support and it does seem to import twice. :(